# access html div within xml, using xsl for transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<item>
<title>Testing WebForm</title>
<link>http://linkurlhere.com</link>
<description>
  <div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary 
   field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"     
   property="content:encoded"><div style="background-color: white; width: 100%;">
  <div id="prize" style="background-color: yellow; color: #660000; font-weight: 
   bold; width: 200px;">Prize here</div>
  </div>
  <div id="startDate">Start Date: January 1, 2013</div>
  <div id="endDate">End Date: January 1, 2014</div>
  <p></p>
  <p>Thanks for playing please take the survey - mock intro</p>
  </div></div></div></description>
 </item>
```

I need to display the `<description>` node's div id=prize.

Is there a way to access that with a xsl:value-of ?

There will be n number of these items, so I would like to place these within an xsl:for-each

So it would look something to this effect:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
display value of <description><div id="prize">content</div></description>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSL should be written like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document" name="document">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item" name="item">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="description">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description" name="description">
        <xsl:value-of select=".//div[@id='prize']" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

where `<document>` is assumed as root element of your xml file.

Edit: If you have three `<item>` and divs has different values like `<div id="prize">Prize here 1</div>` and `<div id="prize">Prize here 2</div>` and `<div id="prize">Prize here 3</div>` then it will print ***Prize here 1 Prize here 2 Prize here 3***  Here I have given one generic solution to traverse `<item>` elements if there are many. If you have one or many same will work accordingly.

Comment: In `//descendant::div`, `descendant::` is redundant. If you want the value-of to select only `div`s that are descendants of the current `description`, use `.//div`. As shown, your stylesheet will select every `div[@id='prize']` multiple times (once per `item/description`).

Comment: @LarsH: Good to pointing out. I have updated answer with more details

Comment: Thanks for the replies....I have the following: `<xsl:for-each select="item"><xsl:apply-templates select="description" /></xsl:for-each><xsl:template match="description" name="description"><xsl:value-of select=".//div[@id='prize']" /></xsl:template>`   and i am not getting any prize value returned...?

Comment: Ok, update......I run this xml and xslt through Altova XML IDE and it shows the correct prize for the correct item/description. However, when I run it in my browser (running on a local 6.0 tomcat server) it does not display the prize....any ideas?

Comment: Actually above XSL should work with the XML you specified. As you also said that you tested it with Altova XML IDE and it shows correct prize. "Why it's not working in 6.0 tomcat server? I don't have any idea about tomcat server."

Answer (score 1):

Within the for-each,

```
<xsl:value-of select="description//div[@id='prize']" />
```

Comment: Im not getting anything returned to the page Lars, is there something I am needing on my xsl stylesheet? `<div id="thePrize"><xsl:value-of select="description/div[@id='prize']" /></div>`

Comment: more specifically my IDE (eclipse) is spitting an error, xpath is invalid

Comment: @user1689274: I don't see anything syntactically wrong with the above XPath. But do note my edit, that there should be a double `//` after `description`. Depending on what it means by "invalid", that could be the problem.